# Редактор кода не видит синтаксис html

Tags: javascript, html, css, sublime-text, редактор-текста

Sublime text не видит синтаксис в файле index.html скачанном из интеренета с помощью web downloader. Подсветка не работает именно в этом файле, в остальных файлах всё светится нормально.

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- This site was created in Webflow. http://www.webflow.com --><!-- Last Published: Tue Oct 16 2018 11:58:06 GMT+0000 (UTC) --><html data-wf-domain="momentum-template.webflow.io" data-wf-page="5af49de0dbb1e358142d8887" data-wf-site="5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886" data-wf-status="1"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Landing page template - Webflow HTML website template</title><meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"><meta content="Webflow" name="generator"><link href="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/css/momentum-template.webflow.7a4e83543.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">WebFont.load({  google: {    families: ["Gothic A1:300,regular,500,600,700,800"]  }});</script><!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]--><script type="text/javascript">!function(o,c){var n=c.documentElement,t=" w-mod-";n.className+=t+"js",("ontouchstart"in o||o.DocumentTouch&&c instanceof DocumentTouch)&&(n.className+=t+"touch")}(window,document);</script><link href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"><link href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/webclip.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"></head><body class="body"><div class="hero"><div data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" data-doc-height="1" class="nav w-nav"><div class="nav-inner"><div class="nav-logo-wrap"><a href="#" class="brand w-nav-brand"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5af4a442dbb1e30d142d8f6c_logo-white.png" width="120" alt=""></a></div><div class="nav-menu-wrap"><nav role="navigation" class="nav-menu-2 w-nav-menu"><a href="#about" class="nav-link w-nav-link">About</a><a href="#features" class="nav-link w-nav-link">Features</a><a href="#how-to-use" class="nav-link w-nav-link">How to Use</a><a href="#download" class="nav-link w-nav-link">Download</a></nav><div class="menu-button w-nav-button"><div class="menu-icon w-icon-nav-menu"></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="section center"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b1437cbda3c5c3369fe4460_arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow"><div data-w-id="6b220cb1-4b9c-7fb0-75b9-53ff4a6c35a2" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 30PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 30PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 30PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 30PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="hero-content"><h1 class="heading-3">Momentum</h1><h3 class="hero-subhead">Launch your product — and savor the momentum. </h3><a href="" class="button w-button">Get the App</a></div><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10d0ee7f483cdf4e9ca8f8_img-top.png" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10d0ee7f483cdf4e9ca8f8_img-top-p-500.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10d0ee7f483cdf4e9ca8f8_img-top.png" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 80vw, (max-width: 991px) 70vw, 100vw" data-w-id="77e69727-c455-8e07-0990-833a661c94ea" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 60PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 60PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 60PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 60PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" alt="" class="hero-image"></div><div id="about" class="section wide img"><div data-w-id="b126983d-9126-fc06-c81d-1318685e2add" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="wrap"><div class="title">Aenean Consectetur Porta</div><h2>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</h2></div><div class="wrapper"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device.png" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device-p-500.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device-p-800.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device-p-1080.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device-p-1600.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device.png" sizes="90vw" alt=""></div></div><div class="section"><div id="features" class="feature-wrap"><div data-w-id="4593c4b7-56e8-060a-be57-648b0e08fc65" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="feature-content"><div class="title">Aenean Consectetur</div><h2 class="black">Cay sociis nato que penatibus et</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. </p></div><div class="feature-image"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c6a9804c1fef0bd52833_app-06.png" width="341" alt="" class="image-2"></div></div><div class="feature-wrap reverse"><div data-w-id="cafe0045-d304-79d9-8f68-af3adaed06e9" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="feature-content"><div class="title">ConsectUltricies </div><h2 class="black-text">Amet Ipsum </h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. </p></div><div class="feature-image"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11bd467f519f18c7efccba_app-05.png" width="386" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11bd467f519f18c7efccba_app-05-p-500.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11bd467f519f18c7efccba_app-05.png" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 40vw, 25vw" alt="" class="image-2"></div></div><div class="feature-wrap"><div data-w-id="88086931-0bbf-a2f5-1fc3-58d79ba19b7e" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="feature-content"><div class="title">Aenean Consectetur Porta</div><h2 class="black-text">Magna Porta Sit Bibendum</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. </p></div><div class="feature-image"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10d56ff2733b40d5e55e64_app-04.png" width="341" alt="" class="image-2"></div></div><div class="feature-wrap icons"><div class="feature-content icons"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11be7f11a9de6a863497c0_icon-burger-magenta.svg" width="80" alt="" class="feature-icon"><h4 class="black-text">Activity Notifications</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. </p></div><div class="feature-content icons"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11be87d0d5fe5d7ff154af_icon-silverware-magenta.svg" width="74" alt="" class="feature-icon"><h4 class="black-text">Custom Timing</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. </p></div><div class="feature-content icons"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11be8e11a9dee3ed3497c6_icon-data-magenta.svg" alt="" class="feature-icon"><h4 class="black-text">Mobile Optimized</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. </p></div></div><div class="feature-wrap icons numbers"><div class="feature-content icons numbers"><div class="number">+12k</div><h4 class="black-text">Nibh Elit Tristique</h4></div><div class="feature-content icons numbers"><div class="number">84</div><h4 class="black-text">Aenean Condimentum </h4></div><div class="feature-content icons numbers"><div class="number">3,07</div><h4 class="black-text">Quam Inceptos</h4></div><div class="feature-content icons numbers"><div class="number">24h</div><h4 class="black-text">Ullamcorper </h4></div></div><div id="how-to-use" class="feature-wrap"><div data-w-id="0585a81c-ee42-8b56-bc8e-bd582946320a" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="feature-content"><div class="title">Aenean Consectetur Porta</div><h2 class="black-text">Sem Risus Elit Vestibulum</h2><p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. <a href="#">Cras mattis consectetur</a> purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p></div><div class="feature-image"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003.jpg" width="519" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003-p-500.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003-p-1080.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003-p-1600.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 90vw, (max-width: 767px) 40vw, (max-width: 991px) 45vw, 27vw" alt="" class="image-2"></div></div><div class="feature-wrap reverse"><div data-w-id="d79d0682-95d0-be91-6539-b82f492963f4" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="feature-content"><div class="title">Aenean Consectetur Porta</div><h2 class="black-text">Parturient Tortor</h2><p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. <a href="#">Cras mattis consectetur</a> purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p></div><div class="feature-image"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002.jpg" width="519" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002-p-500.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002-p-1080.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002-p-1600.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 90vw, (max-width: 767px) 40vw, (max-width: 991px) 45vw, 27vw" alt="" class="image-2"></div></div><div data-animation="slide" data-nav-spacing="8" data-duration="500" data-infinite="1" data-w-id="321c18fb-db93-7e62-3afc-4dab2862f5d4" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="quote-slider w-slider"><div class="w-slider-mask"><div class="w-slide"><div class="quote-wrap"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b14481dda3c5c4b9bfe5147_quotation.svg" width="58" alt="" class="quote-icon"><h3>HeadNulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Pus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.ing</h3><div class="quote-attribution"><p>Joshua Home</p><div class="quote-dash"></div><p><strong>New York Times</strong></p></div></div></div><div class="w-slide"><div class="quote-wrap"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b14481dda3c5c4b9bfe5147_quotation.svg" width="58" alt="" class="quote-icon"><h3>HeadNulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Pus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.ing</h3><div class="quote-attribution"><div class="quote-dash"></div><p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p><p><strong>New York Times</strong></p></div></div></div></div><div class="left-arrow w-slider-arrow-left"><div class="slider-arrow w-icon-slider-left"></div></div><div class="right-arrow w-slider-arrow-right"><div class="slider-arrow w-icon-slider-right"></div></div><div class="slide-nav w-slider-nav w-slider-nav-invert w-round"></div></div><div data-w-id="23f92271-dba9-fb12-00d3-758ef4d10fb2" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="feature-wrap logos"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos.png" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos-p-500.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos-p-800.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos-p-1080.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos-p-1600.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos.png" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 90vw, (max-width: 3885px) 70vw, 2720px" alt=""></div></div><div class="bottom-image-wrap"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps.jpg" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps-p-500.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps-p-1080.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps-p-2000.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 2500px) 100vw, 2500px" alt=""></div><div id="download" class="section wide purple"><div data-w-id="376e2a1f-ec70-0dab-11ea-b1863101e37b" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="wrap"><h2>Ready to get started?</h2><div class="button-wrap"><a href="" class="button w-button">Download Now</a><a href="" class="button contact w-button">Get in Touch</a></div></div></div><div class="section wide"><div data-w-id="8cf47482-19f1-1f52-25ba-910a60bc91de" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 40PX, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);opacity:0" class="wrap"><h2>Get updates from Richard</h2><p>New course alerts, discounts and free lessons</p><div class="form-block w-form"><form id="email-form" name="email-form" data-name="Email Form" class="form-2"><input type="text" class="input w-input" maxlength="256" name="email-2" data-name="Email 2" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email-2" required=""><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" data-wait="Please wait..." class="button form-button w-button"></form><div class="w-form-done"><div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div></div><div class="w-form-fail"><div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.</div></div></div></div><div class="wrapper"></div></div><div class="footer"><div class="wrap"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b149b03d0d5fe3279f270f1_icon-footer.png" width="136" alt=""><div class="footer-list"><a href="" class="footer-link">Email</a><a href="" class="footer-link">Instagram</a><a href="" class="footer-link">Facebook</a><a href="" class="footer-link">Twitter</a><a href="image-license-info.html" class="footer-link">Image License Info</a><a href="http://webflow.com" class="footer-link">Powered by Webflow</a></div></div></div><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/js/webflow.85c1db4b0.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif]--></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вставить отформатированный код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This site was created in Webflow. http://www.webflow.com -->
<!-- Last Published: Tue Oct 16 2018 11:58:06 GMT+0000 (UTC) -->
<html data-wf-domain="momentum-template.webflow.io" data-wf-page="5af49de0dbb1e358142d8887" data-wf-site="5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886" data-wf-status="1">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Landing page template - Webflow HTML website template</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
  <meta content="Webflow" name="generator" />
  <link href="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/css/momentum-template.webflow.7a4e83543.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Gothic A1:300,regular,500,600,700,800"]
      }
    })
  </script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9
            ]><script
                src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"
            ></script
        ><![endif]-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    !(function(o, c) {
      var n = c.documentElement,
        t = " w-mod-";
      (n.className += t + "js"),
      ("ontouchstart" in o ||
        (o.DocumentTouch && c instanceof DocumentTouch)) &&
      (n.className += t + "touch")
    })(window, document)
  </script>
  <link href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/webclip.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div class="hero">
    <div data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" data-doc-height="1" class="nav w-nav">
      <div class="nav-inner">
        <div class="nav-logo-wrap">
          <a href="#" class="brand w-nav-brand"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5af4a442dbb1e30d142d8f6c_logo-white.png" width="120" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-menu-wrap">
          <nav role="navigation" class="nav-menu-2 w-nav-menu">
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link w-nav-link">About</a
                            ><a href="#features" class="nav-link w-nav-link"
                                >Features</a
                            ><a href="#how-to-use" class="nav-link w-nav-link"
                                >How to Use</a
                            ><a href="#download" class="nav-link w-nav-link"
                                >Download</a
                            >
                        </nav>
                        <div class="menu-button w-nav-button">
                            <div class="menu-icon w-icon-nav-menu"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section center">
            <img
                src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b1437cbda3c5c3369fe4460_arrow.svg"
                alt=""
                class="arrow"
            />
            <div
                data-w-id="6b220cb1-4b9c-7fb0-75b9-53ff4a6c35a2"
                style="
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    opacity: 0;
                "
                class="hero-content"
            >
                <h1 class="heading-3">Momentum</h1>
                <h3 class="hero-subhead">
                    Launch your product — and savor the momentum.
                </h3>
                <a href="" class="button w-button">Get the App</a>
        </div>
        <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10d0ee7f483cdf4e9ca8f8_img-top.png" srcset="
                    https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10d0ee7f483cdf4e9ca8f8_img-top-p-500.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10d0ee7f483cdf4e9ca8f8_img-top.png
                " sizes="(max-width: 479px) 80vw, (max-width: 991px) 70vw, 100vw" data-w-id="77e69727-c455-8e07-0990-833a661c94ea" style="
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 60px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 60px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 60px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, 60px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    opacity: 0;
                " alt="" class="hero-image" />
      </div>
      <div id="about" class="section wide img">
        <div data-w-id="b126983d-9126-fc06-c81d-1318685e2add" style="
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    opacity: 0;
                " class="wrap">
          <div class="title">Aenean Consectetur Porta</div>
          <h2>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device.png" srcset="
                        https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device-p-500.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device-p-800.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device-p-1080.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device-p-1600.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa1b861bc189407c1a9b2c_dash-device.png
                    " sizes="90vw" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <div id="features" class="feature-wrap">
          <div data-w-id="4593c4b7-56e8-060a-be57-648b0e08fc65" style="
                        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0)
                            scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)
                            skew(0, 0);
                        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        opacity: 0;
                    " class="feature-content">
            <div class="title">Aenean Consectetur</div>
            <h2 class="black">Cay sociis nato que penatibus et</h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-image">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c6a9804c1fef0bd52833_app-06.png" width="341" alt="" class="image-2" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-wrap reverse">
          <div data-w-id="cafe0045-d304-79d9-8f68-af3adaed06e9" style="
                        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0)
                            scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)
                            skew(0, 0);
                        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        opacity: 0;
                    " class="feature-content">
            <div class="title">ConsectUltricies</div>
            <h2 class="black-text">Amet Ipsum</h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-image">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11bd467f519f18c7efccba_app-05.png" width="386" srcset="
                            https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11bd467f519f18c7efccba_app-05-p-500.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11bd467f519f18c7efccba_app-05.png
                        " sizes="(max-width: 479px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 40vw, 25vw" alt="" class="image-2" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-wrap">
          <div data-w-id="88086931-0bbf-a2f5-1fc3-58d79ba19b7e" style="
                        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0)
                            scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)
                            skew(0, 0);
                        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        opacity: 0;
                    " class="feature-content">
            <div class="title">Aenean Consectetur Porta</div>
            <h2 class="black-text">Magna Porta Sit Bibendum</h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-image">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10d56ff2733b40d5e55e64_app-04.png" width="341" alt="" class="image-2" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-wrap icons">
          <div class="feature-content icons">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11be7f11a9de6a863497c0_icon-burger-magenta.svg" width="80" alt="" class="feature-icon" />
            <h4 class="black-text">Activity Notifications</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-content icons">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11be87d0d5fe5d7ff154af_icon-silverware-magenta.svg" width="74" alt="" class="feature-icon" />
            <h4 class="black-text">Custom Timing</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-content icons">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11be8e11a9dee3ed3497c6_icon-data-magenta.svg" alt="" class="feature-icon" />
            <h4 class="black-text">Mobile Optimized</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-wrap icons numbers">
          <div class="feature-content icons numbers">
            <div class="number">+12k</div>
            <h4 class="black-text">Nibh Elit Tristique</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-content icons numbers">
            <div class="number">84</div>
            <h4 class="black-text">Aenean Condimentum</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-content icons numbers">
            <div class="number">3,07</div>
            <h4 class="black-text">Quam Inceptos</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-content icons numbers">
            <div class="number">24h</div>
            <h4 class="black-text">Ullamcorper</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="how-to-use" class="feature-wrap">
          <div data-w-id="0585a81c-ee42-8b56-bc8e-bd582946320a" style="
                        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0)
                            scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)
                            skew(0, 0);
                        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        opacity: 0;
                    " class="feature-content">
            <div class="title">Aenean Consectetur Porta</div>
            <h2 class="black-text">Sem Risus Elit Vestibulum</h2>
            <p>
              Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.
              <a href="#">Cras mattis consectetur</a> purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-image">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003.jpg" width="519" srcset="
                            https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003-p-500.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003-p-1080.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003-p-1600.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa50601bc189f92b1ad1f1_img-003.jpg
                        " sizes="(max-width: 479px) 90vw, (max-width: 767px) 40vw, (max-width: 991px) 45vw, 27vw" alt="" class="image-2" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-wrap reverse">
          <div data-w-id="d79d0682-95d0-be91-6539-b82f492963f4" style="
                        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0)
                            scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)
                            skew(0, 0);
                        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                            rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                        opacity: 0;
                    " class="feature-content">
            <div class="title">Aenean Consectetur Porta</div>
            <h2 class="black-text">Parturient Tortor</h2>
            <p>
              Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.
              <a href="#">Cras mattis consectetur</a> purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-image">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002.jpg" width="519" srcset="
                            https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002-p-500.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002-p-1080.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002-p-1600.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5afa506095815377cd097a34_img-002.jpg
                        " sizes="(max-width: 479px) 90vw, (max-width: 767px) 40vw, (max-width: 991px) 45vw, 27vw" alt="" class="image-2" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-animation="slide" data-nav-spacing="8" data-duration="500" data-infinite="1" data-w-id="321c18fb-db93-7e62-3afc-4dab2862f5d4" style="
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    opacity: 0;
                " class="quote-slider w-slider">
          <div class="w-slider-mask">
            <div class="w-slide">
              <div class="quote-wrap">
                <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b14481dda3c5c4b9bfe5147_quotation.svg" width="58" alt="" class="quote-icon" />
                <h3>
                  HeadNulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Pus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis
                  euismod.ing
                </h3>
                <div class="quote-attribution">
                  <p>Joshua Home</p>
                  <div class="quote-dash"></div>
                  <p><strong>New York Times</strong></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-slide">
              <div class="quote-wrap">
                <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b14481dda3c5c4b9bfe5147_quotation.svg" width="58" alt="" class="quote-icon" />
                <h3>
                  HeadNulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Pus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis
                  euismod.ing
                </h3>
                <div class="quote-attribution">
                  <div class="quote-dash"></div>
                  <p>
                    Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.
                  </p>
                  <p><strong>New York Times</strong></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="left-arrow w-slider-arrow-left">
            <div class="slider-arrow w-icon-slider-left"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="right-arrow w-slider-arrow-right">
            <div class="slider-arrow w-icon-slider-right"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-nav w-slider-nav w-slider-nav-invert w-round"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-w-id="23f92271-dba9-fb12-00d3-758ef4d10fb2" style="
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    opacity: 0;
                " class="feature-wrap logos">
          <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos.png" srcset="
                        https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos-p-500.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos-p-800.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos-p-1080.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos-p-1600.png,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b11c4dc541a84578a131910_logos.png
                    " sizes="(max-width: 991px) 90vw, (max-width: 3885px) 70vw, 2720px" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-image-wrap">
        <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps.jpg" srcset="
                    https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps-p-500.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps-p-1080.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps-p-2000.jpeg,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b10cd0c3a8396da6772516b_bg-apps.jpg
                " sizes="(max-width: 2500px) 100vw, 2500px" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div id="download" class="section wide purple">
        <div data-w-id="376e2a1f-ec70-0dab-11ea-b1863101e37b" style="
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    opacity: 0;
                " class="wrap">
          <h2>Ready to get started?</h2>
          <div class="button-wrap">
            <a href="" class="button w-button">Download Now</a
                    ><a href="" class="button contact w-button">Get in Touch</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section wide">
        <div data-w-id="8cf47482-19f1-1f52-25ba-910a60bc91de" style="
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
                        rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);
                    opacity: 0;
                " class="wrap">
          <h2>Get updates from Richard</h2>
          <p>New course alerts, discounts and free lessons</p>
          <div class="form-block w-form">
            <form id="email-form" name="email-form" data-name="Email Form" class="form-2">
              <input type="text" class="input w-input" maxlength="256" name="email-2" data-name="Email 2" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email-2" required="" /><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" data-wait="Please wait..." class="button form-button w-button"
              />
            </form>
            <div class="w-form-done">
              <div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-form-fail">
              <div>
                Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="wrap">
          <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/5b149b03d0d5fe3279f270f1_icon-footer.png" width="136" alt="" />
          <div class="footer-list">
            <a href="" class="footer-link">Email</a
                    ><a href="" class="footer-link">Instagram</a
                    ><a href="" class="footer-link">Facebook</a
                    ><a href="" class="footer-link">Twitter</a
                    ><a href="image-license-info.html" class="footer-link"
                        >Image License Info</a
                    ><a href="http://webflow.com" class="footer-link"
                        >Powered by Webflow</a
                    >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5af49de0dbb1e3637f2d8886/js/webflow.85c1db4b0.js"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 9
            ]><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script
        ><![endif]-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: это работает, как вы его отформатировали и в чём причина не рабочей подсветки ?

Comment: @Gybernaty я пользуюсь плагином prettier, при сохранении форматируется код и  он становится читабельным.